# Generating Range Between in Dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

Im generating a data frame in R studio. with 4 columns ITA,Probablity,Cummulative Probablity & Range

My code is working good

```
InterArrivalInput <- list(InterArrival = c(1,2,3,4),
                      Probability = c(0.25,0.40,0.20,0.15))
countDF <- function(input) {


Cumulative <- cumsum(input$Probability)
Range <- (Cumulative * 100) 

df <- data.frame(InterArrivals = input$InterArrival,
               Probability = input$Probability,
               Cumulative = Cumulative,
               Range = Range
}
```

currently its calculating range for e.g **25** for 0.25 cumulative probablity.

```
Commulative | Range
0.25        | 25
0.65        | 55
```

How can i generate range column as

```
Commulative | Range
0.25        | 0 - 25
0.65        | 26 - 55
```

Im starting to learn R language. Don't know if its possible or not. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```r
Range <- c(25, 55)
mapply(paste, c(1, 1 + head(Range, n=-1)), Range, sep = " - ")
# [1] "1 - 25"  "26 - 55"
```

The `head(..., n=-1)` is retrieving everything except that last `1` entries (so `head(..., n=-3)` retrieves everything except the last 3).

`mapply` is a "zipping" version of the apply functions, where if I were to unroll it and show how the function (first argument) is called repeatedly, it would look like this:

```r
c(1, 1 + head(Range, n=-1))
# [1]  1 26
Range
# [1] 25 55
paste(1, 25, sep = " - ")
# [1] "1 - 25"
paste(26, 55, sep = " - ")
# [1] "26 - 55"
```